# Guidelines for using ASP.NET Panels/multiview vs separate pages

Tags: asp.net

It's often necessary to create a UI to walk a user through a multi-step process. There is two common designs that one could use. One option is to make each step a separate page. Another option is to use either asp:panels or the multiview control and keep all the code within one asp.net page.

Whenever I use the seperate page approach, I find that data sharing between pages is kludgy.

Whenever I use the multiview approach, I find that the code-behind logic loses cohesion. It's dealing with too many items at once and gets hard to follow.

What criteria do you use when deciding which approach to use?

Is there other design patterns that could help with the limitations I find in the existing options?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a fan of cross-page postbacks in webforms, and agree that your markup and codebehind can quickly spiral out of control when using MultiViews.

Maybe a sensible compromise would be a MultiView but with each step encapsulated as a separate user control. That way you don't have to fight against the postback model and still get a reasonable degree of code separation.

Comment: The codebehind does not have to spiral out of control.  If you are using partial classes, you can break code for different views into different files easily.

Comment: True, and you could also make the same argument for using #region blocks instead of partials. It's down to personal preference of course but I'd consider using either method to organise a large class as a likely smell.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution mind you but, you also have the [Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) option in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

In classic ASP.NET WebForms, I have found using a panel for each page is the best option.  I am just going to assume that you are using Master Pages as well.

To keep the handling of panels simple (pages from the user's point of view), I use something like this:

```
void ShowPanel(Panel panel)
{
    firstPagePanel.Visible = false;
    secondPagePanel.Visible = false;
    ...
    lastPagePanel.Visible = false;

    panel.Visible = true;
}
```

Calling that means that only one panel is visible at once and so I just treat each panel as a separate page.  You can use in-page panels if you want and just keep them out of the ShowPanel method.

The code-behind logic is ever only dealing with a single event-handler at a time (like button click, drop-down change, or whatever).  The first thing I do in each of these handlers is a `ShowPanel(theRightPanel);` which makes sure that all the other panels have gone away and the panel that relates to the action I want (like showing the next page of the process) is showing.  If the last event was to move to a new page, I populate the data for that page from within the event handler.  You can even wire-up the page specific event handlers here if you want.

I tend not to use ViewState myself (disable it) and I try to avoid referring to controls on panels that are not showing for the handler I am dealing with.  I prefer to pass any data around in Session variables or even to pass it along via hidden inputs in the current form and handle them as postback values in the next one.  You can add hidden inputs dynamically to the form so they do not have to be present in the static mark-up. This helps me better encapsulate the functionality and stay more closely aligned with what is actually happening on the web.

Basically, I am just treating the event handlers like POSTs from the page.

Finally, with partial classes you can even split your code-behind code into chunks where the code for each page (or panel) is in it's own file.  This really avoids one giant code file where it is hard to see what does what.  Not much you can do for the .ASPX page though other than the fact that at least each 'page' will be within an ` element.  It will get big if you have a lot of panels.  At least shutting off ViewState can keep that from growing massive.

All the Page_Load method is doing is setting up the first page of the multi-page process.  Each of the following pages has it's own event handler that triggers it.  I wite-up the event handlers in OnInit (which is where I typically disable ViewState as well).

I also really try to keep code out of the ASPX page itself and really use Code Behind.  This is one of the things that still makes ASP.NET MVC smell for me.  Also, there is a lot you can do to keep your code behind modular and to allow testability and such.  That is a bit beyond your question though.